# pandas .to_sql timing out with RDS

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, amazon-rds

I have a 22 million row .csv file (~850mb) that I am trying to load into a postgres db on Amazon RDS. It fails every time (I get a time-out error), even when I split the file into smaller parts (each of 100,000 rows) and even when I use `chunksize`.

All I am doing at the moment is loading the .csv as a dataframe and then writing it to the db using `df.to_sql(table_name, engine, index=False, if_exists='append', chunksize=1000)`

I am using create_engine from sqlalchemy to create the connection: `engine = create_engine('postgresql:database_info')`

I have tested writing smaller amounts of data with `psycopg2` without a problem, but it takes around 50 seconds to write 1000 rows. Obviously for 22m rows that won't work.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: If you just want to import the csv file into the database, you can probably better use the postgresql `COPY` command, so you don't need the roundtrip to python objects (which makes it slower).

Comment: Further, what driver are you using? (`psycopg2` ?) As 50s for 1000 rows is much slower as what I experience with a postgres database. So maybe it is also partly the connection to the database that is slow.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I have tried using psycopg2. I'll update the question.

Comment: Did you try out the `COPY` approach? If you don't want to use SQL commands but stay in python, you can look at `odo`, which uses a `COPY` command under the hood to transfer data from CSV to SQL: http://odo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: For AWS Postgres RDS, you need the psql /copy command, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46969474/using-python-to-upload-large-csv-files-to-postgres-rds-in-aws/46969475#46969475

Answer (score 3):

The pandas DataFrame.[to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)() method is not especially designed for large inserts, since it does not utilize the [PostgreSQL COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html) command.
Regular SQL queries can time out, it's not the fault of pandas, it's controlled by the database server but can be modified per connection, see [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-client.html) and search for 'statement_timeout'.

What I would recommend you to do is to consider using Redshift, which is optimized for datawarehousing and can read huge data dumps directly from S3 buckets using the [Redshift Copy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) command.

If you are in no position to use Redshift, I would still recommend finding a way to do this operation using the [PostgreSQL COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html) command, since it was invented to circumvent exactly the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: OK, so just to be clear, I should dump my data into an S3 bucket and then use PostgreSQL COPY, right?

Comment: Yes, if the PostgreSQL COPY command lets you specify an s3 bucket to read from in the version of PostgreSQL you are using in RDS. Redshift does allow this, and since they are very closely related, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can to write the dataframe to a cString and then write this to the database using the copy_from method in Psycopg which I believe does implement the PostgreSql COPY command that @firelynx mentions.

```
import cStringIO
dboutput = cStringIO.StringIO()
output = output.T.to_dict().values()   
dboutput.write('\n'.join([ ''.join([row['1_str'],'\t',
                                    row['2_str'], '\t',
                                    str(row['3_float'])
                                    ])   for row in output]))
dboutput.seek(0)
cursor.copy_from(dboutput, 'TABLE_NAME')
connenction.commit()
```

where output is originally a pandas dataframe with columns [1_str, 2_str, 3_float] that you want to write to the database.